# What does this line imply?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

In the following text, what does the bold line imply:

> In the coming weeks, there will be other reviews of Urwand’s book in major publications and in blogs, but **for now I would like to plant a suggestion that will undoubtedly be greeted with derision by any publishing executive who hears of it**: Urwand did some good digging, found some interesting things, but organized his book poorly and hurled all sorts of unprovable accusations. Harvard should acknowledge these problems and correct them in a revised edition that is better informed, if less sensational—for its own sake and for the sake of Urwand’s career as an historian.
>
> -- [*New Yorker (2003)*](http://www.newyorker.com/online/blogs/culture/2013/09/how-could-harvard-have-published-ben-urwands-the-collaboration.html)

Comment: Another question you asked suggests that you are confused here by the word *that*, which is here being used as a relativizer or relative pronoun (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_clause)) rather than as a [complementizer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementizer) or subordinator.

Answer (score 2):

It means that what he is about to say, will be looked upon as ridiculous (*greeted with derision*) by publishing executives if they read this (*... who hears of it*).

"Plant a suggestion" means that he is suggesting something, as a way of giving the readers an idea of what could have be done to fix the issue. He wants this to happen, but has not a big expectation that it will be done.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see much room for implications here other that he assumes to know the reaction of his readers.

> The author is about to give an opinion that he likes to discuss or wants to see other >people discuss  (*plant a suggestion*)
>
> He knows others will find this opinion questionable and he is ready for upcoming mockery
> (*... will undoubtedly be greeted with derision*)
>
> The people he expects reactions from are likely to be professional publishers
> (*any publishing executive who hears of it*)